# Calculation of Variance using data target instead of data mean

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

Given a sequence of data Eg:

```
data = [30.5, 31.01, 30.4, 30.01, 29.5, 29.6, 29.63, 30.5, 30.33, 30.2]
```

I use numpy to get the data variance.

```
Xi = np.var(data, ddof=1)
```

This function uses the mean value instead of target value.

```
mean = 30.168

target = 30

n = number of elements 

#variance = sum(X1,X2...Xn - mean)^2/n-1
```

This is how numpy do the calculation for a given sequence of data, but if the target value is defined (T) the calculation must be performed with the target instead of mean.

```
#variance = sum(X1,X2...Xn - target)^2/n-1.
```

Do anyone know a method to calculate the variance using target instead of mean?

Answer (score 4):

You could just roll your own with this:

```
target = 30
Xi = ((np.array(data) - target)**2).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit more flexibility to CumminUP07 answer regarding degrees of freedom:

```
target = 30
ddof = 1

var = sum((np.array(data) - target) **2) / (len(data)-ddof)
```

Output:

```
0.264
```

Comment: you're missing the `2` for squaring it, but yes, that is how you would include the degrees of freedom.

Comment: Totally missed the 2! Thanks for noticing it!